# SAPUI5 Fragment Value setValue not working

Tags: sapui5

We have set the value of input on click of button on a Fragment Dialog.

```js
sap.ui.getCore().byId("idFragment--txtLatitude").setValue(position.coords.latitude);
```

But the Value is not displaying on UI. If we close and open the dialog again, the value is appearing. Even the console `getValue` showing the value.

Comment: post some code to check with the issue

Comment: Please, update your question with more code. It's like  going to a doctor. Just saying that you have a stomachache doesn't help us much. We have to know exactly what you did before.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the UI control and hierarchy. Generally when have a control as a dependent of another control.

Once we made control as part of the content of the parent control and it worked.